# How to write a properties file using WriteProperties Gradle API?

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I am trying to write some key-value pairs to a properties file in a gradle task. I looked up that Gradle provides an api [WriteProperties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.WriteProperties.html) for that, but I was unable to use it.

I tried different approaches (I am learning Gradle, so I don't know if I used some incorrect syntax):

1.

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        WriteProperties {
            outputFile = file 'prop.properties'
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
            properties = [TEST:42]
        }
    }
}
```

2. 

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        def writer by register(WriteProperties.class) {
            outputFile = file 'prop.properties'
            encoding = 'UTF-8'
            properties = [TEST:42]
        }
    }
}
```

3. 

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        // Other stuff
    }
}

task writeProperty(type: WriteProperties) {
    outputFile = file 'prop.properties'
    encoding = 'UTF-8'
    properties = [TEST:42]
}

writeProperty.dependsOn myTask
```

4. 

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        // Other stuff
    }
    finalizedBy writeProperty
}

task writeProperty(type: WriteProperties) {
    outputFile = file 'prop.properties'
    encoding = 'UTF-8'
    properties = [TEST:42]
}
```

5. 

```
task myTask {
    doLast {
        // Other stuff
    }
}
class MyPlugin implements Plugin<Project>{
    void apply(Project project) {
        project.task('writeProperty') {
            WriteProperties {
                outputFile = file 'prop.properties'
                encoding = 'UTF-8'
                properties = [TEST:42]
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: MyPlugin
writeProperty.dependsOn myTask
```

None of them created a file with the values. Is there some other way to do it? I wanted to know the proper way of using the WriteProperties api, since the documentation did now have any helpful examples.

I found solutions with java syntax to create Properties() object and writing to file, but none with this api.

Answer (score 0):

I'm creating a property file like so, using pure Gradle/Groovy:

```
file "$buildDir/prop.properties" write [ TEST:42 ].collect{ k, v -> "$k=$v" }.join( '\n' )
```

OR

```
file "$buildDir/prop.properties" withWriter{ out ->
  [ TEST:42 ].each{ k, v -> out << k << '=' << v << '\n' }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a Gradle upgrade and Google suggested this question because you googled `"The WriteProperties.outputFile property has been deprecated"`, the property you're probably looking for is `destinationFile`.

Change:

```
outputFile = file(".../META-INF/build-info.properties")
```

to:

```
destinationFile = file(".../META-INF/build-info.properties")
```